# Is it possible to track of battery consumption by all installed app on ios device?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to track the battery usage of all insatalled and system applications in iOS devices.

I hope it would look like this:

[image: picture of a power app]

Is it possible to do this, if it is possible how to estimate the battery usage by all apps?

Comment: This is on a jailbroken phone I assume?

Comment: no, I Found a app on itunes which display battery usage of all app, see I attached screen shot of app https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6fjzi480ijzwj2/Screenshot%202013.04.15%2013.41.22.png

Comment: so? you do not like it ?

Comment: I want to do same but how they do it, anybody have a idea?

Comment: Are you looking for an app that will do what you desire? Or, are you wanting to develop an app that does that? Would you be willing to edit your questions with more details of what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I want to develop an app that display battery consumption by all app but I have no idea how we get battery consumption of app.

Comment: Mahesh, what's the app name of your screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

There is a app called [Carat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/carat/id504771500) that might be overkill but it is way better than just watching the consumption.

It actually recommends what to do to save battery life.

One drawback is, it will not imminently show what needs to be done.

It will take >24 hours of monitoring your usage and then make recommendations on which apps to kill and how much battery life you get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8, this is built-in.

Settings => General => Usage => Battery Usage.

The top section shows overall usage, the bottom section breaks it down by app.  You can see last 24 hrs or last 7 days.